# Deploy Models within an R package

Tags: r

I have four different models I have created from keras, and saved as `.h5` files. These are saved within my R package in a folder called `models`.

I have an R package where I would like to use these models within one of my functions.

How can I accomplish this without specifying the exact path of these models. This package need to be deployed on many different computers throughout the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions for including datasets in R packages using devtools, documented in [Wickham's development guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) and in this [bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/data-within-a-package.html).

Basically, use `devtools::use_data()` to properly save the data to the package's `data/` folder. Then, users and/or the package can call the data as needed.